# when I run fairseq command line structures on colab, I always got ' returned non-zero exit status 2'

Tags: google-colaboratory

I followed the tutorials of fairseq on https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/docs/tutorial_simple_lstm.rst
and https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/docs/tutorial_classifying_names.rst . I just copy the code on the tutorial to colab, but when I run the command line I always got the same bug.

```
%%shell
fairseq-train names-bin \
  --task simple_classification \
  --arch pytorch_tutorial_rnn \
  --optimizer adam --lr 0.001 --lr-shrink 0.5 \
  --max-tokens 1000
```

It should work but I got the bug blow.

```
CalledProcessError: Command 'cd /content
fairseq-train names-bin \
  --task simple_classification \
  --arch pytorch_tutorial_rnn \
  --optimizer adam --lr 0.001 --lr-shrink 0.5 \
  --max-tokens 1000' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

So how can I fix it?